# Magento Configurable Product Attributes

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

hey guys, having an issue with magento which i just cant seem to find a solution to.

i have tried many ways of getting a configurable products attributes (simple products) and listing them, now i have them listing from 2 ways but the way im working with is below

```
$confAttributes = @$_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
```

`$sizes = array();

    foreach($confAttributes AS $atts){
        //print '';//'<pre style="display:none;">'.print_r($atts).'</pre>';
        if($atts['label'] == 'Size'){

            foreach($atts['values'] AS $val){

                $sizes[] = $val['store_label']; 

            }   

        }

    }`

my only problem with this now is i need to only pull back the size attributes which are in stock - looked through mage files to find solution but just cant see anything - the result i need is done in config product php file but i cant access it from in the code where i need to list the size attribute.

any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: so you need the products that have size attributes and are in stock?

Comment: hi Anton, when going onto a configurable product i needed to get the various sizes it came in, in the right order and only in stock, i managed to get this after alot of digging about. :D all sorted now! yay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution, i had to use the above what i had already coded and use assosicated products for the size and then check the stock levels and put them into an array and check the stock when building my attribute list - works great - anyone else have a better solution please share :D thanks

Comment: just add the size and stock attribute to product collection as filter and you are done no need to access them through "snake pen*is" :)

Comment: @AntonS What do you mean "add the size and stock attribute to product collection"? I see the $_productCollection variable in list.phtml, but I'm not sure how I would add the stock attribute so that specific options for a configurable product won't show if they are out of stock.

Comment: you can join them to collection

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
You can get easily all configurable(product) details page information on any other PHTML file by using following code:
e.g.: in my case i'm getting details on catalog/product/list.phtml.

```
 <script src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js') ?>varien/configurable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <?php
        $temp = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable();
        $temp->setData('product', $_product);                    
        $_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($temp->getAllowAttributes()); 
        ?>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
            <?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
            <?php
                $prices = $_attribute->getPrices();
                foreach($prices as $price) {
                    echo $price['pricing_value'] . "<br/>";
                }
            ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $temp->getJsonConfig() ?>);
            </script>
        <?php endif;?>
```

Thanks,

Comment: thanks - I no longer have this issue but will still check it out and get back to you - thanks!